# create an element in other columns of a data frame based on one column element name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns ce, si, ps, se. I have to create an element in ce, ps, se columns based on respective si column value. for example if value of si column is "SIRR" then corresponding ce, ps, se columns values will be Newce_SIRR_1, Newps_SIRR, Newse_SIRR_1 respectively. below is the data frame for your reference

Input:

```
 ce         si          ps          se
 cedummy1  SIRR       psdummy     sedummy1
 cedummy2  SI234      psdummy     sedummy2
 cedummy   SI67K      psdummy     sedummy
```

expected output:

```
ce              si          ps          se
Newce_SIRR_1     SIRR     Newps_SIRR    Newse_SIRR_1
Newce_SI234_2    SI234    Newps_SI234   Newse_SI234_2
Newce_SI67K_3    SI67K    Newps_SI67K   Newse_SI67K_3
```

value of column 'si' should be append to every other columns values like above data frame. and for columns 'ce' and 'se' sequence id should be there at end.

```
createNewElement <- function(input, element, use_element_in_name, prefix, postfix_sep, include_si_name = FALSE)
{
    toappend <- input %>%
        mutate(rootname = ifelse(include_si_name, get("si"), if(use_element_in_name) get(element) else "")) %>%
        group_by(rootname) %>%
        mutate(idname = c(1:n())) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        mutate(new_name = paste0(prefix, rootname, postfix_sep, idname))
        
        toappend %>%
        mutate(!!element := new_name) %>%
        select(-rootname, -idname, -new_name)   
}

  createNewElement(input, element = "ps", use_element_in_name = FALSE, prefix = "Newps_", postfix_sep = "", include_si_name = TRUE)
  createNewElement(input, element = "ce", use_element_in_name = FALSE, prefix = "Newce_", postfix_sep = "_", include_si_name = TRUE)
  createNewElement(input, element = "se", use_element_in_name = FALSE, prefix = "NewSe_", postfix_sep = "_", include_si_name = TRUE)
```

above code is not working as expected, it is taking first value of 'si' and appending to all the rows in other columns below is the result I am getting

```
  ce              si          ps          se
Newce_SIRR_1    SIRR     Newps_SIRR    Newse_SIRR_1
Newce_SIRR_2    SI234    Newps_SIRR    Newse_SIRR_2
Newce_SIRR_3    SI67K    Newps_SIRR    Newse_SIRR_3
```

Comment: After I provided the answer below, I went ahead and debugged your code. The error is in the `ifelse`: since `include_si_name` is a logical vector of length 1, it only collects the first element of the `true` condition (in this case the first element of `get("si")`). To fix it, replace `include_si_name` with `rep(include_si_name, n())` in the `ifelse`. I recommend using `if_else` instead, which would've thrown an error instead of assuming you're only interested in the first element in this case.

Comment: Thank you, `rep(include_si_name, n()) ` is working fine. now I am able to get 'si' value for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr::str_glue` there is an elegant solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>% 
  mutate(ce = str_glue("Newce_{si}_{row_number()}"),
         ps = str_glue("Newps_{si}"),
         se = str_glue("Newse_{si}_{row_number()}"))
```

Which gives

```
  ce            si    ps          se           
  <glue>        <chr> <glue>      <glue>       
1 Newce_SIRR_1  SIRR  Newps_SIRR  Newse_SIRR_1 
2 Newce_SI234_2 SI234 Newps_SI234 Newse_SI234_2
3 Newce_SI67K_3 SI67K Newps_SI67K Newse_SI67K_3
```

Input data:

```
input <-  read_table("ce         si          ps          se
cedummy1  SIRR       psdummy     sedummy1
cedummy2  SI234      psdummy     sedummy2
cedummy   SI67K      psdummy     sedummy")
```

Comment: I have some changes in requirement , have created new question below is the link. can you please help in that 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426258/create-values-in-other-columns-of-a-data-frame-based-on-the-input-column-in-same]

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `paste`

```
df1[c(1, 4)] <- Map(function(x, y) paste0("New", y, "_", df1$si, 
          "_", seq_along(x)), df1[c(1, 4)], names(df1)[c(1, 4)])
df1$ps <- paste0("Newps_", df1$si)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ce = c("cedummy1", "cedummy2", "cedummy"), si = c("SIRR", 
"SI234", "SI67K"), ps = c("psdummy", "psdummy", "psdummy"), se = c("sedummy1", 
"sedummy2", "sedummy")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```