# create values in other columns of a data frame based on the input column in same data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with columns ce, si, ps, se. I have to create values in ce, ps, se columns based on respective si column value and also 'ce' column value will be depends on se column.

For example

1. if value of si column is "SIRR" then corresponding ce, ps, se columns values will be Newce_SIRR_1, Newps_SIRR, Newse_SIRR_1 respectively and 'se' column value can have multiple 'ce' values like
2. if 'se' value is Newse_SIRR_1 then its corresponding 'ce' column values should be Newce_SIRR_1_1, Newce_SIRR_1_2, Newce_SIRR_1_3
3. if input given for no.of 'ce' to create is 3(this input is common for all se values, have to create 3 ce's under every se). Below is the pictorial representation for the same.

[image]

In above picture ce1, ce2, ce3 values will be part of 'ce' column in the data frame.(picture is just to understand).

There is a relationship between columns one si column value will have one ps value, multiple se values. again one se column can have multiple ce values, you can notice the same in picture as well.

input: below data frame and integer value to add no.of ce's per se. In this example it is 3, per every 'se' there will be 3 'ce'

```
si         ps             se          ce         
SIE      dummyps        dummyse     dummyce
SIA      dummyps1      dummyse1     dummyce1
SIC      dummyps2      dummyse2     dummyce2
....  so on
```

Below is the expected output data frame.

```
si           ps              se             ce         
SIE      Newps_SIE        Newse_SIE_1     Newce_SIE_1_1
SIE      Newps_SIE        Newse_SIE_1     Newce_SIE_1_2
SIE      Newps_SIE        Newse_SIE_1     Newce_SIE_1_3

SIA      Newps_SIA        Newse_SIA_1     Newce_SIA_1_1
SIA      Newps_SIA        Newse_SIA_1     Newce_SIA_1_2
SIA      Newps_SIA        Newse_SIA_1     Newce_SIA_1_3

SIC      Newps_SIC        Newse_SIC_1     Newce_SIC_1_1
SIC      Newps_SIC        Newse_SIC_1     Newce_SIC_1_2
SIC      Newps_SIC        Newse_SIC_1     Newce_SIC_1_3
....  so on
```

Below is my previous question but this question is change in the previous question

[link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410492/create-an-element-in-other-columns-of-a-data-frame-based-on-one-column-element-n/63419758#63419758)

Comment: updated the expected output data frame, I missed to update those rows

Comment: input (no.of ce to add per se) will be given  i.e no.of ce required for se (3 given in above example). Here 'si' is parent. se is child to si and ce is child to se. we will receive data frame with si values and integer input for no.of ce to add.

Comment: `SIE` and `SIC` has 2 se's each. if you take `SIE`  it has 2 se one is `Newse_SIE_1` and second is `Newse_SIE_2` . Each se value has 3 ce values.  `Newse_SIE_1` has 3 ce and `Newse_SIE_2` has 3 ce.  input is 3 so each se value should have 3 ce, if input is 4 each se value should have 4 ce values.

Comment: let me explain, I will receive a data frame with `si` values and also will receive no.of `se` and no.of `ce` need to add to that `si` value. lets consider for si value `SIE` I have to add 2 se and for each se I have to add 3 ce values.  you can check `SIE` in expected output data frame. since I will receive a fixed number to add no.of se and ce, means the input will be same for all the si values. I have updated the output data frame